# jedis version compatible for redis 5.0.2

Tags: redis, jedis

I am trying to use the latest redis 5.0.2 for my java code which uses jedis client 3.0.0 library ([jedis-git-repo](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis)). It doesn't work.
Same code works with redis 4.x.
My query is - git page of jedis says

> Jedis is fully compatible with redis 2.8.x and 3.x.x.

but I can see it works fine with redis 4.x (at-least for my use-case), so has someone tried jedis 3.0.0 with redis 5.x?

----- update --------------

this is snippet of the actual code, below code is in different classes, for explanation purpose I have clubbed it together.

```
JedisCluster jedisCluster = new JedisCluster(jedisClusterNodes,initPoolConfiguration());
Map<String, String> mapContentFolder = new HashMap<String, String>();
mapContentFolder.put(INDEX_COLLECTION, /* json object */);
jedisCluster.hmset(id, mapContentFolder);
```

the last line from code snippet is line no.220 in saveCache() method.

So I get below exception(while saving to redis) when I run this code with jedis client jar as 3.0.0 and redis as 5.0.2 -

```
2018-12-13 10:42:32.568  INFO 14420 --- [nio-9097-exec-2] o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet                : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 30 ms
redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
        at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:53)
        at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.getResource(JedisPool.java:226)
        at redis.clients.jedis.JedisSlotBasedConnectionHandler.getConnectionFromSlot(JedisSlotBasedConnectionHandler.java:66)
        at redis.clients.jedis.JedisClusterCommand.runWithRetries(JedisClusterCommand.java:116)
        at redis.clients.jedis.JedisClusterCommand.runWithRetries(JedisClusterCommand.java:141)
        at redis.clients.jedis.JedisClusterCommand.runWithRetries(JedisClusterCommand.java:141)
        at redis.clients.jedis.JedisClusterCommand.runWithRetries(JedisClusterCommand.java:141)
        at redis.clients.jedis.JedisClusterCommand.runWithRetries(JedisClusterCommand.java:141)
        at redis.clients.jedis.JedisClusterCommand.run(JedisClusterCommand.java:31)
        at redis.clients.jedis.JedisCluster.hmset(JedisCluster.java:424)
        at com.abc.om.repository.redis.AbstractCRUDRepository.saveCache(AbstractCRUDRepository.java:220)
        at com.abc.om.mle.engine.DefaultCatalogProcessor.processPlanFragments(DefaultCatalogProcessor.java:27)
        at com.abc.om.mle.v1.restapi.MleApiController.planFragmentModel(MleApiController.java:50)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:849)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:760)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:207)
        at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.connect(BinaryClient.java:93)
        at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.connect(BinaryJedis.java:1767)
        at redis.clients.jedis.JedisFactory.makeObject(JedisFactory.java:106)
        at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:888)
        at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:432)
        at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:361)
        at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:49)
        ... 66 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:184)
        ... 73 more
```

and the same code works fine with jedis client library as 3.0.0 and redis 4.x

Thanks,
Saurabh.

Comment: Can you elaborate and give some examples on how it works with Redis 4.x but not 5.x?

Comment: @sazzad, I have updated my post.

Comment: Your main concern should be `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect`. I see that you're using cluster. Check configuration of every node, specially `bind` and other security related parameters.